# Parse a datatable using multithreading and an async method

Tags: multithreading, datatable, async-await

I have a datatable with hundreds of thousands of records. I want to use multithreading in order to save time when trying to geocode this records. My issue is that i have to use an async method and wait for its result. i know that Parallel.ForEach doesn't work with async-await.

```
            if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                DataRow[] dataRow = dataSet.Tables[0].Select();
                Parallel.ForEach(dataRow, (currentRow) =>
                {
                    //SendCustomerNotification(currentRow);
                    inputAddress = currentRow[addressColumnIntex].ToString();

                    // Geocode the suggestion and get a list of matches
                    IReadOnlyList<GeocodeResult> matches = geocoder.GeocodeAsync(inputAddress).Result;
                    foreach (var item in matches)
                    {
                        //Store in GeocodingTable
                        string logString = " insert into .....";
                        using (SqlConnection sql_conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=....;Initial Catalog=....;User ID=....;Password=..."))
                        {
                            sql_conn.Open();
                            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(logString, sql_conn))
                            {
                                comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                comm.CommandTimeout = 600;
                                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use asynchronous concurrency:

```
if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
{
  DataRow[] dataRow = dataSet.Tables[0].Select();
  var tasks = dataRow.Select(async currentRow =>
  {
    //SendCustomerNotification(currentRow);
    inputAddress = currentRow[addressColumnIntex].ToString();

    // Geocode the suggestion and get a list of matches
    IReadOnlyList<GeocodeResult> matches = await geocoder.GeocodeAsync(inputAddress);
    foreach (var item in matches)
    {
      ...
    }
  });
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

However, I should caution you that parallelizing access to a database may cause a self-imposed denial of service.